# Question in Curve Discussion

Tags: analysis

I am practising maths and would love to get some hellp in this exercise.

$$f(x)=-1/4 \cdot (x-1)^2(x+4)$$

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What does the exercise consist of?